# ADD Unadvertised WMS layer to QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, geoserver, wms

I want to create a plugin that adds a raster layer (published on geoserver) on QGIS via PYQGIS.
As long as i enable the advertised option in the layer publish panel the layer is easily added on the QGIS.
But when I unchecked the advertised option, the layer is not added.
So, please suggest a method through which i can create a custom plugin that adds published WMS layer (whose layer preview is OFF) on the QGIS desktop?

Comment: The whole point of making a layer unadvertised is to prevent people from loading it,

Comment: So is there no way to do this. It is working in ArcGIS

Comment: why would you want to load an unadvertised layer?

Comment: Actually we want to share our vector data in raster form with a client as a service.So i published the vector data on my geoserver and now the client wants to visualize the data on QGIS so we thought to make a custom plugin that does it all

Comment: QGIS can read a WMS layer just fine, simply click advertised in GeoServer so it shows up in the GetCapabilities list of layers and all WMS clients can use it.

Comment: why is it working in arcgis?

Comment: probably because arcgis ignores the getcapabilities and asks you for a layer name? no idea really as I don't use arcgis

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95616/discussion-between-gaurav-and-ian-turton).

Answer (score 1):

A "good" client like qgis will query the getcapabilities response to find out what layers are available, unadvertised layers will not show up in that list. A lazy client will rely on you adding the layer name you want (leaflet, arcgis) - an attacker can read you leaflet JS and will know the layer name and so you have no security.

Therefore you should use the [security system built into GeoServer](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/layer.html) to restrict access to your layer in a standardised way.

Answer (score 0):

Either,

Make a copy of the GeoServer GetCapabilities response, add the layer(s) you want. Save the static file to a location on a web server. Point QGIS to this static file.

Or,

Configure a GDAL WMS driver configuration file and add your required layers there.

See https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/wms.html